# find closest value pair in python list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary as so:

```
d = {'ID_1':[(10, 20), (40, 60), (125, 200)], 'ID_2': [(75, 100), (250, 300)]}
```

and a position and ID:

```
pos = 70
IDed = ID_1
output = (40, 60)

pos = 90
IDed = ID_2
expected output = (75, 100)

pos = 39
IDed = ID_1
expected output = (40, 60)
```

I would like to find the value pair in the list that is closest to the test `pos`.

I've tried this below:

```
if IDed in d:
    y = d[IDed]
    closest = min(y, key=lambda x:abs(x-pos))
```

This doesn't work because it's not a list with single values. Is there another way to do this using a similar method. If not, I can find a long way around the problem by indexing through the list and calculating the distance between each value pair. However, I don't think this would be very efficient.

Comment: you have to be a bit more specific on what *closest* is. Would that tuple still be the closest its items where `(69, 100000000)`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis yes, that would be considered the closest. I'll add more examples

Comment: What if there's a pair `(60,69)` and another one `(50,90)`?

Comment: Are these Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: @Rawing two value pairs like that would not be present in the list because they overlap. The values in the individual lists would never overlap

Comment: @interstellar What about `[(40, 69), (71, 90)]`? Who wins?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis in that case, it wouldn't really matter. Either value pair would be accepted. The first value would probably be preferential

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were really close. Bellow is a working solution.

```
d = {'ID_1': [(10, 20), (40, 60), (125, 200)], 'ID_2': [(75, 100), (250, 300)]}    
pos = 70
IDed = 'ID_1'

closest = min(d[IDed], key=lambda x: min(abs(y - pos) for y in x)) if IDed in d else None    
print(closest)
# (40, 60)
```

The problem with your code was that you were trying to do `x - pos` with `x` being the entire tuple (e.g., (40, 60)) and `pos` being the integer-target value.

---

You can consider wraping that in  a function to avoid code repetition in case you need to run it multiple times.

```
def find_nearest(point_dict, id, stigma):
    try:
        return min(point_dict[id], key=lambda x: min(abs(w - stigma) for w in x))
    except:
        return None

d = {'ID_1': [(10, 20), (40, 60), (125, 200)], 'ID_2': [(75, 100), (250, 300)]}
print(find_nearest(d, 'ID_1', 70))
# (40, 60)
```

Note that the order in which the terms appear in the list nested in the initial dictionary is important in cases like `d = {'ID_1': [(10, 20), (40, 69), (71, 200)], ...}` for example. Terms `69` and `71` are equidistant from given target `70` but the code returns `(40, 69)` since it finds that **first**.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you!! I felt like there must have been an easier way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to find the couple which has the closest average with pos value...
 So this is the answer:

```
d = {'ID_1':[(10, 20), (40, 60), (125, 200)], 'ID_2': [(75, 100), (250, 300)]}
pos = 70

closest = (0, 0)

IDed = "ID_1"

for i in d.items():
    if IDed == i[0]:
        for x in i[1]:
            avg = (x[0]+x[1])/2
            avg_closest = (closest[0]+closest[1])/2
            if abs(pos-avg) < abs(pos-avg_closest):
                closest = x

print closest
```

Comment: that's not what OP wants (based on the first two comments)